# Symfony3 Doctrine : Fetch entities as arrays with all associations for performance improvement

Tags: performance, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, fetch

I have 2 entities : Product and Tag. A product can has 0 or one tag.

**Product entity :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=35, nullable=true)
 */
private $tagCode;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tagCode", referencedColumnName="tagCode")
 */
private $tag;
```

I have a page where I want to list all my products.
I use KnpPaginator bundle to paginate my 1000+ results (50 per page).

**ProductController** `listAction()`

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.code ASC');

// Pagination
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $request->query->getInt('page', 1), 50);

return $this->render('products/list.html.twig', array(
    'products' => $pagination
));
```

It works well but **it's a little bit too time consuming** (more than 7 seconds to display 50 first results).

Instead of fetching my products as entities (my entities are quite large with a lot of dependencies and associations), I would like to use arrays (for increasing the page loading speed).

Besides, I want to show just some properties of my entity Product.

- product name
- product code (= primary key)
- tag code (= secondary key)
- tag name

I tried to use `$query->getArrayResult()` but it doesn't return `Tag` object and I have to get `Tag` object to show the tag name in twig :

```
{% for product in products %}
    ...
    <td>{{ product.tag.name }}</td>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

`$query->getArrayResult()`  returns an array of products like this :

```
array (size=3)
  'code' => string 'TEST' (length=4)
  'name' => string 'My product' (length=10)
  'tagCode' => string 'mytag' (length=5)
```

My question is : how to get `Tag` object (or tag name) in my array of results ?